# Prove that the set of vectors is a subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ and $C=\{c_1,c_2,c_3\}$ are two basis of a vector space $W$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and $b_1=2c_1−c_2−c_3,b_2=−c_2,b_3=2c_2+c_3$. Prove that the set of all vectors which have the same coordinates in both basis is the subspace of $W$. Find a basis and dimension of that subspace.

$$c_1=2c_1-c_2-c_3\Rightarrow c_1-c_2-c_3=0\Rightarrow c_1=c_3$$
$$c_2=-c_2\Rightarrow c_2=0$$
$$c_3=2c_2+c_3$$
$$b_1=c_3,b_2=0,b_3=c_3$$

Now we need to show that $X=\{c_3,0,c_3\}$ is a subspace of $W$.

$1)$ Is it correct to conclude that $X$ is the subset of $W$ because $B,C$ span $W$?

$2) $$$\forall w_1,w_2\in W,\forall t\in\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow w_1+w_2\in W,tw_1\in W$$

$$w_1=\alpha c_1+\beta 0+\gamma c_3$$
$$w_2=xc_1+y0+zc_3$$
$$w_1+w_2=(\alpha+x)c_1+(\beta+y)0+(\gamma+z)c_3\in W$$
$$tw_1=t\alpha c_1+t\beta 0+t\gamma c_3\in W$$

From $1)$ and $2)$ $\Rightarrow$ $X$ is the subspace of $W$.

If this is correct, how to find a basis and dimension of $X$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you intented.

A natural way is, taking $V=\{u\in W| \mbox{$u$ has the same coefficientes in both bases}\}$, characterize $V$ by mean of some equations.

Set $u\in V$. Then,

$\begin{eqnarray*}
u&=&\alpha_1c_1+\alpha_2c_2+\alpha_3c_3\\&=&\alpha_1b_1+\alpha_2b_2+\alpha_3b_3\\&=&\alpha_1(2c_1-c_2-c_3)+\alpha_2(-c_2)+\alpha_3(2c_2+c_3)\end{eqnarray*}$,

wich give us $(\alpha_1-2\alpha_1)c_1+(\alpha_2+\alpha_1+\alpha_2-2\alpha_3)c_2+(\alpha_3+\alpha_1-\alpha_3)c_3=0$. Using independence of $c_1,c_2,c_3$ give us $\alpha_1=0$ and $\alpha_2=\alpha_3$.

Then, $V=\{\alpha_2c_2+\alpha_2c_3|\alpha_2\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Clearly $V$ is a subspace of $W$ and a base for $V$ is $c_2+c_3$, from which $\mathrm{dim} V=1$.